# Android layout issue for high end devices

Tags: android

Am a newbie to Android UI...
I got the layout below which is basically a image view, a image button (that is hidden until a certain logic is met) and another image view at the bottom.

This layout works fine in ldpi devices but look bad on other devices... I also had to resize the image by changing its height so it influence the quality of the image.

How can I resolve this by having a standard view that will work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeTutorialImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/welcome_tutorial"
        android:src="@drawable/welcome_tutorial_browse" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/welcome_tutorial_start_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/welcomeTutorialImage"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_startsavingstatic" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeTutorialProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/welcome_tutorial_start_btn"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/welcome_tutorial"
        android:src="@drawable/welcome_tutorial_bar1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at android:fitXY property of ImageView. Also, post screenshots that could explain the issue further. There might be a need to have different sized images for different screen sizes/resolutions (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi)

Answer (score 0):

most of the time, you have to adjust the layout and the image resolution for your application to make it flexible with other devices by placing them to the right folder  like:

```
-drawable
-drawable-1280x752
-drawable-800x480
-drawable-hdpi
-drawable-ldpi
-drawable-mdpi etc.

-layout
-layout-land-1280x752
-layout-800x480
-layout-land
etc.
```

by placing your layout and image to there designated folder, you have to change each layout and image sizes that will much the requirement of each folder.

and if you need further reference you can check this out
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html